# pycurl installation on Windows

Tags: python, libcurl, pycurl

I am not able to install pycurl on Windows on Python2.6. Getting following error:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\vijayendra\Desktop\Downloads\pycurl-7.19.0>python setup.py install --curl-dir="C:\Documents and Settings\vijayendra\Desktop\Downloads\
curl-7.19.5-win32-ssl\curl-7.19.5"
Using curl directory: C:\Documents and Settings\vijayendra\Desktop\Downloads\curl-7.19.5-win32-ssl\curl-7.19.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 210, in <module>
    assert os.path.isfile(o), o
AssertionError: C:\Documents and Settings\vijayendra\Desktop\Downloads\curl-7.19.5-win32-ssl\curl-7.19.5\lib\libcurl.lib
```

Any idea what is this error about and how to fix this?

Comment: The same problem: pycurl developers didn't find useful to support python 2.6 on windows (more than year after general release!). We will not use this library anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://wiki.woodpecker.org.cn/moin/PyCurl?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=pycurl-7.20.1-bin-win32-py26.zip

unzip it and copy all to your site-packages
:)

Comment: Use the installer from the answer below

Answer (score 29):

Andelf's answer didn't work on my Win 7 x64 machine, but [Christoph Gohlke's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) has a package that works for me.

Comment: +1 for providing an answer that actually works. Christop Gohlke's site has PycURL win32 exe's for 32 & 64-bit and for python 2.6 & python 2.7.

Comment: UrlGrabber install worked like a champ for me after using Gohlke's PyCurl installer.

Comment: @RossFabricant - I downloaded PycURL for 64-bit Python 2.7, but got the following message `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.` when I tried importing pycurl. Do you have any idea what I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

You install pyCURL on Windows via the provided win32-specific [binaries](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/).

Comment: there is no python2.6 specific exe for pyCURL :(

Answer (score 2):

Here is the url,

this sites packages are rocks http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycurl

Answer (score 0):

I built pycurl without ssl today for urlgrabber 3.9  and it worked. the dir i used was c:\Pycurl-7.19.0 and same as --curl-dir ,as given CURL_DIR in setup.py, but with fresh compiled libcurl.lib from sources using vc express 08, inside the dir in respective places ie it needs some include files also. try running after the step above for the next err or just check setup.py.

Comment: some of us are using python because we don't have C. so recompiling from source and all that entails for the latest versions (last pycurl on windows was from 2008) is more than we were expecting for a supported Binding... YMMV