# Python 3.7: pycurl installation on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycurl

I've been trying to install pycurl but keep getting the following error.

```
C:\>pip install pycurl
Collecting pycurl
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/e2/xxx/pycurl-7.43.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 10 in C:\Users\sabrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xxx\pycurl\

C:\>
```

This is Python 3.7.0 running on Windows 10.

```
C:\>py -V
Python 3.7.0
```

I've been searching around and found the following question, but he's using Python 2.6
[pycurl installation on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582814/pycurl-installation-on-windows)

I've also found the following link
https://pypi.org/project/pycurl/7.19.5.1/#files

Unfortunately, the binary installer only supports v3.4.

Is there a way to make this works?

Comment: There are [newer installers](https://pypi.org/project/pycurl/#files). Also, that an installer has, say, `py3.6` in its name doesn't necessarily mean it won't work for Python 3.7.

Comment: Just downloaded ... here is the error.

`Python version 3.6 required, which was not found in the registry`

Comment: Welp, then you'd probably have to build libcurl yourself or find a prebuilt version somewhere (probably [here](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html)?).

Answer (score 3):

Compile pycurl for Python 3.7 manually or use unofficial binary of pycurl:

Download whl file of pycurl matching your python version and python architecture from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pycurl). Open the directory in cmd and install with pip:

```
pip install pycurl-7.43.0.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
```